# RAM: 2x8 GB (Dual Channel) + 16 GB, going to work?

Tags: memory

I'm currently have a 16 GB (single slot) and also planning to buy another pair of RAM (2x8 GB) to get a Dual Channel mode.

Question, is it going to work as it should (all together)? New RAM in dual channel mode + old RAM, should work just fine, right?

**Specs**

- Current RAM: KINGSTON ValueRAM DDR4 2133MHz 16GB (KVR21N15D8/16)
- New: HyperX DDR4-2133 16384MB PC4-17000 (Kit of 2x8192) Fury Black (HX421C14FB2K2/16)
- Motherboard: [MSI B150 PC Mate](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B150-PC-MATE/Specification)
- CPU: i7-6700
- GPU: GTX 1070

I can't buy another one old RAM on local market. All this headache is for increasing FPS.

Comment: If you have a single 16 GB module and plan on purchasing two 8 GB modules, you won't end up in dual channel mode, so you won't achieve your primary goal.  You would be better off purchasing, 4 of the same modules.  I assume I have located the correct motherboard, [MSI B150](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B150-PC-MATE/Specification), update your question with the relevant information if that assumption is incorrect.

Comment: So I can just throw away old 16 GB module and just use new ones, to achieve dual channel mode? *Added motherboard link*

Comment: Why would you throw away working hardware?  The performance benefit of doubling your memory would be greater, than running whatever amount of memory in dual channel.  However, you are not going to increase your FPS by doing either, unless your memory is an actual performance bottleneck.

Comment: *unless your memory is an actual performance bottleneck*. This is the point, how can I know is it performance bottleneck or not. That's why I'm thinking about 2x8 GB instead of single 16 GB module. But, you're telling that dual channle mode will not going to help me with increasing the FPS? I'm not happy about removing old RAM module, but if it's worth it.

Comment: The only bottleneck that could exist surrounding memory, would be you are running out of system memory, which is easy to identify due to the errors that are generated.  You might see single-digit increases with additional memory and/or dual channel mode.  The benefits from additional memory would be primarily due to the additional multi-tasking that it brings (but not while task intensive programs are running).

Comment: I didn't have a situation where I was running out of 16 GB. In conclusion, what will be your advice? Keep old and new RAM? But in this case dual channel mode won't work.

Comment: @Scofield it's also possible to put old RAM into the safe anti-static container you recently received.  Don't throw it away, if it's working.  That being said, there is only a small performance benefit from dual-channel mode.  If you're running 20 GB of Chrome tabs, as some people do, then having 32 GB of physical RAM is better than having 16 GB of physical RAM.

Comment: I'll keep old module in any case (or will resell it later). The reason why I want the dual channel it's increasing FPS (in games). I'm totally fine with current setup for general daily tasks and work.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern motherboards will run RAM in dual-channel mode so long as there is the same amount of RAM on each channel. Putting the 16GB stick on one channel and the two 8GB sticks on the other channel will probably result in the RAM operating in dual-channel mode.

Comment: Trusty manual will confirm this but I always thought all slots had to be filled to accomplish that.

Comment: @Ramhound The most common dual-channel configuration is one stick on each channel, which leaves half the slots empty.

Comment: Isn't other properties of memory are also required? Such as timings, CAS latency, not only RAM amount and MHz.

Comment: @Scofield Yes. You will get a speed and latency that works for all your sticks, which may mean that they're not performing as quickly as they could possibly perform. But dual-channel is usually worth it. Note that while dual-channel versus single-channel usually makes a huge difference on synthetic RAM benchmarks (15%-40%), the effect on comprehensive performance metrics such as FPS in games tends to be much less dramatic (2%-4%).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - It’s been awhile I have not filled all memory slots on a motherboard, and you confirmed my suspicions, that dual vs single channel won’t see huge FPS increases. Always appreciate learning something (again).